# Gradient vector field of $C^1$ function on Riemannian manifold

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, vector-analysis

From my understanding, the gradient vector field on a Riemannian manifold $M$ is usually defined for a smooth function $f \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ (e.g., John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds), while it seems natural to define a gradient vector field of a $C^1$ function defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Does defining the gradient vector field of a $C^r$ ($r \neq \infty$) function (e.g., $C^1$ function) on a Riemannian manifold cause any inconvenience? If so, what is the inconvenience? If not, is there any textbook where the gradient for a not $C^{\infty}$ function is defined?

Comment: Typically differential geometers choose to work purely in the $C^\infty$ category to avoid analytical technicalities. There is no deeper reason for this.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: Thanks for your answer. When for example do we encounter an analytical technicality if we deal with a gradient vector field of a $C^1$ but not $C^{\infty}$ function?

Comment: @Cathy If $f$ is $C^1$, then its gradient is only continuous. Thus, one cannot consider the Hessian of $f$, etc.

Comment: @Didier Thanks. I agree with you, but the situation also applies to the case of Euclidean space. I would be even happier to know an example that is specific to the Riemannian manifold case.

Comment: @Cathy As mentioned above, working in the smooth category usually prevents authors to state, for each of the result, which regularity should be used for the results to be true. But keeping track of the definition of the different objects and of the proofs of the different statements, it should be clear what are the natural regularity to consider for each result.

Comment: @Didier Thank you for your comment. I understand.